# Plotting a pattern made of repeating unit blocks but of changing width

Tags: plotting

I am plotting a pattern as illustrated in link shown below. I want to create an image of fixed size.

The whole image should be filled by repeating unit blocks which consist of black and green regions. The width of a unit block and its black region change from `0` to `100` (or even larger values), and from `1` to `0`, respectively.

The ratio between a black region and a unit block is given as `1.055^(-lambda0)`. More preferably, the width of a unit block changes randomly from `Lambda0(1 - errorfactor)` to `lambda0(1 + errofactor)`, so that the average value of the unit blocks are still `lambda0` but each individual block may vary slightly.

[image: diagram]

Comment: Please show us what have you tried. It seems an easy application of `Rectangle[]` ...

Comment: Thank you, Belisarius. That Rectangle[] helped a lot and it is enough. I have tried a few methods, such as plotting parallel lines, arrays, squarewave, but not the Retangle[]! I didn't even now that we have this command. Once you gave me this clue, I got what I had expected.                   I will work on the remaining part that is to make the pattern a little bit irregular of certain fluctuations rather than perfectly uniform. Would you suggest again some possible commands? (I don't know how to copy my codes and image to this tiny input box,they all went messy when I just did that

Answer (score 1):

```
w = 1.055^-λ;
AR = 20;
h = λ*AR*w;
λ = 15;
λmax = 100;
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], Blue,
  Table[{Black, Rectangle[{j, 0}, {j + λ, h}], 
         Green, Rectangle[{i, 0}, {i + w*λ, h}]}, 
    {j, 0, λmax, λ}, {i, 0, λmax, λ}
  ]}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Width  (μm)", "Height", "λ = 15"}, 
 Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Thick, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[{Black, Large, Bold}]]
```

[image: result]

Comment: Sorry, the solution seems ugly because I don't know how to paste the code as it looks in Mathematica.

Comment: Add 4 spaces to the beginning of each code line, or select the code block and hit ctrl+k